# How to implement multi threading in openssl?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openssl

I am trying to setup multi threading in openssl. I went through the link **https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/opensslthreadlock.html**. But i could not understand how to use that. Can you suggest any idea?

Comment: 'Could not understand' is not a problem description.

Comment: The question is about multithreading in openssl, but it is not clear what was tried and the link provided is for locking when using multi threaded programs. Could you please elaborate what you have already tried and what is that you are specifically looking for.

Comment: I had written a server that uses openssl. When i tried multi threading in my server , server crashes. Because multithreading is not supported default in it. So we have to make openssl to support multi threading. How to implement that?

Comment: When you are using multi-threading, you need to take care of thread synchronization, critical sections. When you use multi-threading for openssl, then you need to follow some guidelines what is documented for openssl. It looks like the link you have provided is one such guideline.  Without any details provided on the problem with errors, I do not see a way to respond to your generic query.

Comment: Please don't ask for a tutorial. You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/CRYPTO_THREAD_lock_free.html

And implement your multithreading according to `/crypto/threads/mttest.c` and your target platform. It basically comes to setting two functions (optionally more) at the start of your program.

Nothing more can be said about this, and copying stuff here would make the answer deprecated in next OpenSSL version. Sources are most of the times up-to-date.

Additionally, you can read chapter `Multithread Support` from `Network Security with OpenSSL`from O'Reilly. Keep in mind that some of the functions there are deprecated.

Comment: I did static locking. But also application gets crashing. I will post my code here. Can you see any mistake in it? I am not able to put the code here since it is large. I used the code from openssl source file alone i.e mttest.c (pthread platform code)

Comment: the link referred to does not exist anymore